# Make remote branch take precedence during a merge conflict

Tags: git

I have two branches, `current` and `master`. `current` is dozens of commits ahead of `master` so I think it's time to merge.

I change to `master`

```
git checkout master
```

I attempt to merge with `current`

```
get merge current
```

I get about 20 conflicts of this nature:

```
CONFLICT (rename/add) <remote>
CONFLICT (rename/add) <remote>
```

First question, how do I make the remote branch, `current` take precedence here? I'm working my way through all the conflicts with `git mergetool -t meld` and I'm clicking away, selecting all the remote changes over the local changes.

So how can I do this with one command? I want remote to take presence.

Also, why have these conflicts occurred? I would have thought it obvious that the latest branch would contain the changes we want to keep?

Comment: These conflicts occurred because current and master branch made changes to the same files

Comment: Have a look at the 'merge strategies' paragraph at http://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you are merging you can specify a strategy to use for automatically resolving some conflicts (the comments contain a link to the man page for this http://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge).  You would use the recursive strategy with the option of `theirs`.  This will resolve all conflicts by using the version in the branch that is being merged in.  If you were merging master into your branch, then it would be `ours`.

The command would end up being:

```
git merge -s recursive -Xtheirs current
```

This will resolve ALL conflicts with what is on the branch being merged in.

Before you commit your merge if there are conflicts, I would check the diff with `git diff --staged` carefully.  And run any tests that you have so that you are sure that the conflict resolution didn't overwrite changes on `master` that you actually wanted.

Comment: I run your command, and yet my project doesn't work in master, and yet it works in current? How can this be? Or is this definitely not a git reason?

Comment: Because you are resolving all the conflicts with what is in the remote branch, there may be changes on master that are now broken.  That can happen if their is change on master that depended on change in another file that was conflicted.  The conflict got resolved with what is on current and would end up breaking master.